# Shared unit tests for new multiplatform template in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xcode12

How do you test the shared portion of code when you have a multiplatform project? I see tests for iOS and tests for macOS, but nothing for the shared pieces. I want to add unit tests for the platform-independent portion of my app.

Comment: Hey @PointOfNilReturn curious to learn if you had any success with this? We are currently having the same problem in both beta 4 and beta 5.

Answer (score 8):

#### Required

The most important part is to import the module to the test target:

[image: Code]

The `@testable` word means that this test can access the internal stuff of the imported module.

<sub>Also, note that the `MultiplatformAPP` is the name of my project. You should look for the name of your project, instead.</sub>

---

✅ Now you can access to the shared section and test it as you like. But there are some extra optional works you can do:

---

#### Optionally

1. You can build a custom bundle for your shared test:

[image: Template]

Note that is doesn't matter what template group you are choosing this template from. It's a template! you can change it to anything else anytime. So we started with tvOS ‍♂️

2. Then you can nake it independent to any of the targets or depends on any of them you prefer to test with:

[image: Settings]

Note that I have named it `Tests shared` to match the pattern of the default tests naming convention of the multiplatform app.

Comment: I tried what you suggested with the new target. I had been using testable already. I keep getting an "Undefined symbol:" error. Do I need to select the new test target as a target in the files I wish to test??

Answer (score 3):

Think we managed to figure this out.

If you go to File > New > Target ...

In the Multiplatform section there isn't many options, but in iOS there is a Testing bundle named "Unit Testing Bundle"

[image]

If you add that and name it "Tests Shared"

You can then unit test against files that are part of the Shared target